# how to draw mac spinning wait cursor on application dock icon in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nsdocktile

I want to draw animated dock icon with spinning wait cursor for my cocoa app.
Please let me know how i can draw the spinning wait cursor or where did i find the cursor file on mac.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put cursors anywhere but on the cursor. It would be really bad to make the user think their mouse has locked up.

Make a view that displays your application's icon, make an NSProgressIndicator a subview of it, and make the icon view the view of your application's Dock tile.